# Nginx doesn't route according to my custom rules

Tags: nginx

**Problem**:
Nginx doesn't route traffic based on the rule I have defined in a separate config file, and just displays the default 404 response.

**Context**:
I have a small middleware application written in Go that provides a simple response to GET requests. The application is deployed on port 8080:

```
$ curl localhost:8080
ok
```

I wish to write an Nginx configuration that allows me to route calls from **/api** to **localhost:8080**, which would allow me to do the following

```
$ curl localhost/api
ok
```

To achieve this, I have written the following config:

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/custom-nginx-rules**

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }
}
```

I have also created a softlink in **/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/** for the above file

```
$ ls -l /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 Jan 19 16:42 default -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 Feb 20 14:56 custom-nginx-rules -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/custom-nginx-rules
```

The rest of the setup is vanilla Nginx, nothing is changed.
Despite this simple setup, I get a 404 when making the following call:

```
$ curl localhost/api
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.10.3</center>
</body>
</html>
```

**Other info**: the following are nginx packages installed on my system (running on raspberry pi)

```
$ dpkg -l | grep nginx

ii  libnginx-mod-http-auth-pam      1.10.3-1+deb9u1              armhf        PAM authentication module for Nginx
ii  libnginx-mod-http-dav-ext       1.10.3-1+deb9u1              armhf        WebDAV missing commands support for Nginx
ii  libnginx-mod-http-echo          1.10.3-1+deb9u1              armhf        Bring echo and more shell style goodies to Nginx 
ii  libnginx-mod-http-geoip         1.10.3-1+deb9u1              armhf        GeoIP HTTP module for Nginx
ii  libnginx-mod-http-image-filter  1.10.3-1+deb9u1              armhf        HTTP image filter module for Nginx
ii  libnginx-mod-http-subs-filter   1.10.3-1+deb9u1              armhf        Substitution filter module for Nginx
ii  libnginx-mod-http-upstream-fair 1.10.3-1+deb9u1              armhf        Nginx Upstream Fair Proxy Load Balancer
ii  libnginx-mod-http-xslt-filter   1.10.3-1+deb9u1              armhf        XSLT Transformation module for Nginx
ii  libnginx-mod-mail               1.10.3-1+deb9u1              armhf        Mail module for Nginx
ii  libnginx-mod-stream             1.10.3-1+deb9u1              armhf        Stream module for Nginx
ii  nginx                           1.10.3-1+deb9u1              all          small, powerful, scalable web/proxy server
ii  nginx-common                    1.10.3-1+deb9u1              all          small, powerful, scalable web/proxy server - common files
ii  nginx-full                      1.10.3-1+deb9u1              armhf        nginx web/proxy server (standard version)
```

I also require that this setup is independent of any host or server names. It should do the routing regardless of host.

Running the `nginx -T` command confirms that the files is loaded.
The error log is also empty.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the symlink `default` from `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` and restart nginx.

Otherwise this `default` configuration is used to serve the request before `custom-nginx-rules` is

Comment: Is there no way to keep the default? I wish to only append my changes to the existing setup. And I cannot understand why the default configuration kicks in because, after reading the NGinx docs, the `location` settings with the most specific path are used, which is not happening in my case.

Comment: nginx selects the virtual host first, and the virtual host with `default_server` is used when no other virtual host matches. When a virtual host is selected, nginx starts looking into the `location` blocks for that virtual host. Therefore your requests end up to the default virtual host and nginx never sees your `location` block.